# Error connecting C# web application to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

I'm working on a newly set up laptop. There are two web projects I usually work with. One is fine. The one giving me trouble is a C# Web forms application (ASP.NET 4.5, EF 6.0).

The following is the error I get when trying to connect to the database via the application -

Exception:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Inner Exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.)

Debugging using IIS Express and ASP.NET Development Server give me the same result. My connection string is also good - it's more or less the same as the one in the other project I use, bar their actual names. For clarity here it is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="RetailerEntities" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=db;user id=sa;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"/>
  <add name="RetailerCContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Providers.Model.csdl|res://*/Providers.Model.ssdl|res://*/Providers.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=db;user id=sa;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I should also mention, both projects I work with access the same database, so it is strange that one would connect and one wouldn't.

Funnily enough, there are no issues with this project once it's deployed into a production environment, so it looks to just be a local issue on my laptop. This makes me wonder is it some sort of permissions issue.

The stack trace is:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Retailer.Library.DB.ConfigurationController.GetConfigurations() in c:\Development\Retail\RetailerC.Library\DB\ConfigurationController.cs:line 41
   at RetailerC.Web.Default.BindDdlSearchUrl() in c:\Development\Retail\RetailerC.Web\Default.aspx.cs:line 449
   at RetailerC.Web.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Development\Retail\RetailerC.Web\Default.aspx.cs:line 79
```

If anyone had any ideas, or has experienced anything similar, I'd be grateful to hear.

Comment: Is the DB on your new laptop too?

Comment: Have you tried nuking your .edmx file (if that's what you're using) and regenerating it? No idea if it'll help, but I've had to do that before on occasion when I've ran into similar unexplained EF problems.

Comment: Do you need to allow traffic to port 1433 on your local firewall?

Comment: @Mr.Spock Tried that previous to this post unfortunately, no joy.

Comment: @acfrancis I'm not sure, I'll look into it. It would be strange that I can connect to the same database fine from the other project though wouldn't it?

Comment: Another project and the same DB, both on this new laptop? If so, it's probably not the firewall.

Comment: @acfrancis yea both on new laptop. It's a strange one :-S

Comment: can you connect to SQL Server on your laptop using SQL Server Management Studio?  It sounds like the instance is not running.

Comment: @MaxVernon I can. I have managed to get it working..will post another comment.

Comment: So I've removed 'Network Library=DBMSSOCN;' from both connection strings, and it seems to work. Can't understand why this would make a difference but I'm working away now. Thanks for the comments guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed 'Network Library=DBMSSOCN;' from the connection strings and it seems to be working fine now. Not sure why, but it's done it for me..

Comment: That parameter configures the connection to use TCP/IP.  Without that, the connection uses shared memory to connect.  You can fix this by allowing TCP/IP through the SQL Server Configuration Manager application.